# I am under Impression that the last dimension of Y_TRUE and Y_PRED gets dropped when the model calls the loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am building a Deep Learning model for object classification and localisation using "yolo" approach on Keras and tensorflow. My output for a single input image is a 52*52*10 matrix. So, when I run model.summary(), I get the following output dimension :

```
...
...

leaky_103 (LeakyReLU)           (None, 52, 52, 128)  0           bnorm_103[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_104 (Conv2D)               (None, 52, 52, 256)  294912      leaky_103[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bnorm_104 (BatchNormalization)  (None, 52, 52, 256)  1024        conv_104[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_104 (LeakyReLU)           (None, 52, 52, 256)  0           bnorm_104[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_105 (Conv2D)               (None, 52, 52, 10)   2570        leaky_104[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 52, 52, 10)   0           conv_105[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 55,642,218
Trainable params: 55,592,682
Non-trainable params: 49,536
______________________________________________________________
```

**i.e. output is [None, 52, 52, 10]**

So, as I have to create a custom loss function for my output (as I have to apply cross entropy on `[:,:,0:2]` slice and another loss on `[:,:,2:6]` slice). The following is an excerpt of loss function

```
epsilon = 0.000001
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss1 = K.mean(K.sum(K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true[:,:,:,0:2], y_pred[:,:,:,0:2]), 
                         axis = (1,2,3)), 
                   axis = 0)
    loss2 = K.mean(K.sum(-K.log(K.abs(tf.math.subtract(y_true[:,:,:,2:6],
                                                       y_pred[:,:,:,2:6])) 
                                + epsilon), 
                         axis = (1,2, 3)), 
                   axis = 0)
    return loss1+loss2
```

but while running `model.compile()`, I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 3 for input with 3 dimensions. for 'loss_6/activation_2_loss/Sum_2' (op: 'Sum') with input shapes: [?,52,52], [3] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1 2 3>.

I interpreted that in actual, while calling the loss function, the loss is calculated slice by slice along last dimension and reduced the axis dimensions in loss function, the "modified loss function"
is:

epsilon = 0.000001

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss1 = K.mean(K.sum(K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true[:,:,:,0:2], y_pred[:,:,:,0:2]), 
                         axis = (1,2)), 
                   axis = 0)
    loss2 = K.mean(K.sum(-K.log(K.abs(tf.math.subtract(y_true[:,:,:,2:6],y_pred[:,:,:,2:6])) + epsilon), axis = (1,2)), axis = 0)
    return loss1+loss2
```

after this the model compiled successfully.
Can anyone tell me weather I am right or wrong about my hypothesis.

Comment: It seems your input shape is not correct. How are passing the tensors in the fit function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right: `categorical_crossentropy`, will reduce the last axis (dimension 3). You have "one" loss for the 3 classes, not one loss for each class.

So you input `(batch, 52, 52, 3)` and it returns `(batch, 52, 52)`. Thus your `sum` can only work on dimensions 1 and 2, there is no dimension 3.

You corrected the `loss1` accordingly.

---

About `loss2`, you forgot to add the dimensions for the sum. So it will be in a different order of magnitude, because `loss1` has a `mean` in axis 0 while `loss2` has a `sum` in axis 0.

You need `loss2` as it was before:

```
loss2 = K.mean(K.sum(-K.log(K.abs(tf.math.subtract(y_true[:,:,:,2:6],
                                                   y_pred[:,:,:,2:6])) 
                            + epsilon), 
                     axis = (1,2, 3)), 
               axis = 0)
```

I'm not specialized in this task, but maybe you still have a different order of magnitude there, because `categorical_crossentropy` is performing a mean on axis 3, so your `loss2` might also need this mean:

```
loss2 = K.mean(K.sum(-K.log(K.abs(y_true[:,:,:,2:6] - y_pred[:,:,:,2:6]) + epsilon),
                     axis=(1,2))) #let axis 3 to the mean.
```

---

Hint: the `mean` on axis 0 is optional. Keras will do it for you later. The advantage of leaving dimension 0 untouched is being able to use sample weights later.

Hint 2: `tf.math.subtract(a, b)` is equal to writing `a-b`.